# How to fix these xl2tpd errors?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, strongswan, xl2tpd, zyxel

How to fix these xl2tpd errors?
How to fix these xl2tpd errors? l2tp/ipsec connection. I use xl2tpd along with strongswan.
Strongswan is rising, everything is ok. I see myself connected to the gateway via ipsec. Further xl2tpd, I receive errors.

Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1087]: IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet, enabling force userspace=yes
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1087]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1087]: Not looking for kernel support.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1079]: Starting xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.12 started on user PID:1088
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Forked again by Xelerance ([www.xelerance.com](http://www.xelerance.com)) (C) 2006-2016
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: get_call: allocating new tunnel for host 111.111.111.111, port 1701.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Connecting to host 111.111.111.111, port 1701
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: control_finish: message type is (null)(0). Tunnel is 0, call is 0.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: control_finish: sending SCCRQ
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: network_thread: recv packet from 111.111.111.111, size=77, tunnel=9959, call=0 ref=0 refhim=0
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: message_type_avp: message type 4 (Stop-Control-Connection-Notification)
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: assigned_tunnel_avp: using peer's tunnel 51533
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: result_code_avp: peer closing for reason 2 (General error--Error Code indicates the problem), error = 6 (No IPSec protection for the L2TP tunnel)
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: control_finish: message type is Stop-Control-Connection-Notification(4). Tunnel is 0, call is 0.
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: control_finish: Connection closed to 111.111.111.111, port 1701 (No IPSec protection for the L2TP tunnel), Local: 9959, Remote: 51533
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: build_fdset: closing down tunnel 9959
Jan 31 06:38:52 user xl2tpd[1088]: Will redial in 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. Had to downgrade xl2rp to 1.3.12 and started working again. See here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xl2tpd/+bug/1951832